# boolean iteration with python

Tags: python-2.7, boolean

for some reason this isn't working for me. trying to remove element in list 'lst' that exist in list 'ex'. This should work and it doesn't. However, when i have only one of the elements in the list 'ex', it works. FOr instance it list 'ex' only contained '1' it removes it from the list lst.

```
lst=['1A','1B','1C','1D','1E', \
    '2A','2B','2C','2D','2E', '2F', \
    '3A','3B','3C','3D','3E','3F', \
    '4A','4B','5A','1X','2X','5B','5C','1','2']
ex = ['1','2','1X','2X']    
for el in lst:
    if any(el != x for x in ex):
        print el
```

Comment: any or all? Think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't call this exactly remove, but what you should use here is all instead of any.

A more clear alternate is to use `in` operator.

```
for el in lst:
    if el not in x:
        print el
```

Note this is actually equivalent of saying that all of elements in x must not be the same as el, not any.